# What is the best C++ interview question?

Tags: c++, interview

If you could ask a C++ programmer one question to measure their C++ skills, what would it be?

The question I think is best is: **Can you call "delete this;" inside a member function?** (I put this as a link so you can think it through first, then go to [The Best C++ Interview Question – Ever!](http://blogs.windwardreports.com/davidt/2009/12/the-best-c-interview-question-ever.html) to see the correct answer.)

I don't ask this because I expect most people to know the answer. If they did it would not be that useful a question. I ask to see if they can work their way to the correct answer and how they do so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would ask them for the reason why virtual member function can not be used with template in C++. Of course, there is only few people who can actually answer the question immediately. But if an interviewee properly understands the core mechanics of C++(how template works in C++, how virtual function is implemented, how compiler and linker generate an executable from source code, etc.), you may get an answer with appropriate step-by-step leading questions.

Added : Template virtual member function in this answer means template function that is virtual member function of some class - not a regular member function in template class. Sorry for confusing :(

Comment: @summerlight: I do mix virtual member functions and templates and nothing bad happened so far... So I am afraid I didn't understood what you were getting at. Care to enlighten me :) ?

Comment: This answer is almost but not quite correct. You can't have template virtual member functions, but you can have virtual member functions of a template class.

Comment: My intention was that template virtual member function is not allowed (yeah, you can use template with normal member function), not a virtual member function in template class. If my answer was confusing, it's my fault. :(

Comment: @summerlight: ah got it! Amusing question yes, often pops up ;)

Comment: -1 IIRC Microsoft's ATL library used template classes with virtual member functions all the time. Why shouldn't this work?

Comment: @nikie: That's a virtual member function in template class - not a virtual template member function like template<typename T> virtual void doSomethingWithGenericTypeT(T arg);

Comment: @summerlight: You should have included that example in your post. I had no idea what you meant until now. Good question, though, now that I do understand it ;-)

Answer (score 57):

The best C++ interview question would be a programming problem, not a quiz question.

Comment: Agreed. Don't ask about syntax that can be looked-up on Google. Instead, have the candidate write an easy (though not trivial) function, preferably something that you've written in your own code at one point.

Comment: Even something as simple as "write a function to reverse a string" can tell you a lot about an expert programmer: do they use `CString`, `char*`, `std::string`, etc.; do they return a new string or reverse in place; do they manually loop over the characters or do they call a library function. And of course if they can't do something simple like reverse a string, that also tells you a lot about them! There are also lots of follow-up questions, like does it work with Unicode, does it work with UTF-8, etc.

Comment: Hm, by simply chosing between CString, char*, std::string, etc one would quickly understand why C++ never really took off.

Comment: @Ernelli: C++ never really took off? Seriously?

Comment: c'mon, c++ is all about quiz! how much memory would integer take if he was spying on char* and UTF-8? Oh yeah, hes unchecked! It sounds like c++ question.

Comment: @Gabe - good point. For example, doing a template in-place reverse with a policy parameter would either be not very general, or (probably the policy rather the function) quite complex, when it comes to variable-bytes-per-character strings. I don't know whether no-premature-optimisation (create a new string because it's easier to be general) or agility (don't worry about that case until it happens, and the in-place reverse is no harder, maybe a tad easier, for fixed-width-character strings) would win out.

Comment: @Ernelli - you're forgetting wchar_t and std::wstring and them meaning different things on Windows/Unix

Answer (score 32):

I would ask them what they like about C++0x. From this I could "bucket" them into various stereotypes:

- super old school, uses C++ compilers to compile C code
- old school, scared of (or sees no point to) STL, hasn't been keeping up with the changes
- loves lambdas, loves STL getting faster from rvalue references, big RAII fan, hot to use shared_ptr, unique_ptr etc
- is bitter because all the boost code written over the last few years will need to be adapted to use C++0x equivalents
- insane template metaprogrammer who makes my head explode while answering a relatively short question

Chances are some of these buckets are perfect for you and some are "thanks for coming in". As a question that gets you a lot of information fast, this is my winner.

Comment: +1 for a good leading question that encourages a lot of discussion around the subject.

Comment: You forgot the category of people who have no idea what C++0x is. I guess that would be more of an answer, and would fit the first two types.

Comment: @Fast Fish, yes, people who are like C++0-whatnow? will generally be one of the first two categories, and typically will illuminate that in their answer.

Answer (score 28):

I am somewhat bemused as to why "can you delete this?" is considered to be an interesting question. Anyone who has written COM code in C++ knows that the very first thing you learn on day one of basic COM programming is how to use "delete this" correctly. I suppose it might be useful to determine whether, say, someone is lying on their resume about having written COM programs, but as a general knowledge C++ question, if someone couldn't answer it immediately then they are not going to be a good fit for my team.

Anyway, if your goal is to come up with a question that measures C++ skills, then picking one question is the wrong way to go. *Turn it around.* The right question to ask is:

> On a scale from one to ten, how good a C++ programmer are you?

This is not the question that gets you the answer you want. Everyone says "eight" regardless. The question that gets you the answer you want is:

> OK, so you're an eight. What is a problem area that you think a seven would have a difficult time working with?

And *boom*, now you've got them. If the candidate thinks that "something to do with recursion" or "when to use a virtual destructor" is the sort of thing that a seven has a hard time with, then you know that they know a little bit about recursion or destructors or whatever, and that their knowledge does not go much farther than that.

That should give you much better calibration than coming up with some trivia question. If you were to force me to come up with a good single question about a fact about C++, I'd probably ask something like "how would you design the semantic analyzer and code generator for the portion of a C++ compiler that deals with virtual methods called in a base class destructor?"  You should ask questions that have to do with real stuff that you work on, and that the candidate is likely to work on. That's a problem I had to work on once, and I think it would give a pretty good insight into how a person designs semantic analyzers and code generators, as well as their knowledge of C++.

Comment: I'm going to start using this one: OK, so you're an eight. What is a problem area that you think a seven would have a difficult time working with?

Comment: Another good question here:  what could a nine do that you'd have trouble with?

Answer (score 14):

Just for fun, I've had C++ programmers reeling with this little baby:

**Why does this run into an infinite loop (and yes it's typed correctly)?**

```
int x=0;
while (x<3) {
  x = x++;
}
```

It's amazing how many get tripped up. Of course, I can't use it any more [after it appeared on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226002/whats-the-difference-between-x-x-vs-x). Mutter... mutter...

(To get the proper answer read the confession and definitely read the comments)

**Added bonus question**

There is the all-time classic FizzBuzz (as featured in the now-famous [Coding Horror article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/02/why-cant-programmers-program.html)). I've never actually used it in an interview myself, but after chucking it around the development team one lunchtime the results were... um... surprisingly accurate.

**Confession**

I was caught up on the standard "x++ returns the original value" response. However, the correct answer is that the behaviour is undefined because of sequence points. Nobody ever mentioned sequence points in all the times I used this until I posted it here.

I have been educated and I'd genuinely like to thank all those who have taken the time to comment.

Comment: Gary Rowe: Whilst I love that example (first time I've seen it). It does sadden me that people do not see that fairly quickly, let alone not know.

Comment: Umm... that's not a very hard question. You can even guess the answer (even if you don't know exactly why): x never changes. Why else would it be infinite? How about ask them the difference between `x = x++` and `x = ++x` and what they expect the behavior to be.

Comment: @Everyone Yes, I know it's easy. It's even obvious if you look at it. Still, so many candidates turn pale and freeze up. So, in that respect, it does work well as a first filter. For kicks, take a look at the lower scoring answers on the linked question. That's what I would see.

Comment: When I was at Microsoft I started asking applicants to do an insert in a linked list. Why? Because about 80% couldn't do it. Amazing...

Comment: This is not necessarily an infinite loop. You're invoking undefined behavior here (x is modified twice with no intervening sequence point). And in fact, with my particular compiler, gcc (Debian 4.3.2-1.1) 4.3.2 on my particular arch (x86) it _does_ terminate.

Comment: As Logan pointed out, I'd also like to say it's undefined and not necessarily an infinite loop. You're basically not allowed to modify a memory location twice without the presence of a sequence point. See the C++ FAQ for more detail (http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html#faq-39.16)

Comment: the fizz buz question is a bad question for seeking late binders, its a very good question for compilation, since it can examine the idea of loop unrolling. if i were to write the code i would do for(int i=1;i<=101;i+5)system.out.print(i+" " + (i+1) + "fiz"+ (i+3) + "fiz buz"); this is the most clear code and the fastest one of all suggestions!

Comment: @Logan +1 for mentioning sequence points. You'd get a second interview for sure ;-)

Comment: More info on sequence point for the interested: http://c-faq.com/expr/seqpoints.html

Comment: This is a really good interview question because it tells the candidate whether it's worth coming back for another interview ;-) . If the interview really thinks that the code does result in an infinite loop (and the interviewer is supposed to be technically competent) then the candidate can safely give the "opportunity" a miss.

Comment: @Charles Ouch! :-) As a corollary, surely if during the interview the interviewee points out a flaw in the question and the interviewer has accepted that flaw, that would indicate a good place to work? It would also strongly favour the candidate who pointed it out rather than shying away from upsetting the interviewer.

Comment: @Gary Rowe: It depends on the role, doesn't it? If the opportunity is joining a team as a journeyman developer and they already have a "guru" then it may indicate a difficult time ahead; if the opportunity is to join and technically lead a team who have lost / need a new guru then perhaps it's a good thing.

Comment: @Charles Fair point. So it's a good interview question from both sides really, although more by accident than by design.

Comment: These types of questions are the 2nd most useless possible. Either the person sees it right away or under the stress of the interview they fail to think clearly. In either case, it tells the interviewer ABSOLUTELY NOTHING of the interviewees capabilities on the job.

Comment: I'm sorry if this sounds stupid, but this isn't really an infinite loop, I tried it and it didn't loop forever, am I missing something here?

Comment: @Phobia Did you read the answer completely? It's about sequence points. You won't get an infinite loop in all cases.

Comment: @Dunk Note that the test is for their C++ skills. At the very least they should say "Um - infinite loop? What does x++ return? Can I refer to the C++ reference documentation?" Then the interviewer can probe for more detailed knowledge.

Comment: @Gary I'll read about sequence points then, thank you :)

Comment: I think I would have stumbled on this question if I hadn't read about the difference between ++x and x++ just before.

Comment: So, the (almost truly evil) sequence points have made it into C# too. Horror!! [EDIT] Or, stay, _this_ question is about C++ and _that_ about C#, so that's not it.. Or is it?

Comment: @mlvljr Yep, the reference to the SO question should be clearer. This question is C++ (when I used it) that question is C# and is a weak reference.

Comment: If there is any relevant information in these comments it should be edited into the answer. If you want to continue the discussion, please use [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21)

Comment: @Gary Rowe Never mind, that was fun to read. (But how did `E D I T` (spelled without whitespaces) in my comment turned into a link to editing the answer??)

Comment: @mlvjr You surrounded it with square brackets and it became a [shortcut](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000).

Comment: @Anna Lear Hmm, not sure.. Let's test it: EDIT.
Yep, possibly ;) Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The first thing to ask is a simple question about pointers.  I was astonished to see how many people who claim to know C++ or, even worse, C, are unable to answer it.  Then I would ask a simple question about virtual functions.  This combination tells you very quickly whether or not the person actually knows C++.

Comment: depends on their background, never met someone with a hardware background who didn't understand pointers but some who didn't really get encapsulation or polymorphism

Answer (score 7):

That depends a lot on what kind of C++ is written at your company. (When I had to hire C++ programmers, I never asked about `delete`, because I asked them about techniques to avoid having to write `delete` altogether.)

Ideally, you want to hire people that write code above the level of what your team currently writes, but not too high above it, unless you want to combine this with training the team to take it to a higher level.

Answer (score 7):

> Tell me about the copy constructor.

Comment: +1. That one weeds out the incompetent candidates in five seconds.

Answer (score 6):

I believe I would ask them what else they know, or more likely give them a question in something quite different.

Far too many C++ coders about who have little experience of other languages.  Narrow experience is usually restrictive.

Answer (score 6):

The best question for a great C++ developer is "Tell me the reasons why we should **NOT** use C++ ?"

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a best C++ question. C++ is such a large language, and with C++0X it's grown, that you can be in strong in a certain subdomain of the language and no little about another part of the language. A 'one shot' question will only exercise someone's knowledge of a small part of the language and risk overlooking his or her's knowledge of other aspects of the language.

Answer (score 4):

There's a bunch on StackOverflow. I'll share a few:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428404/tricky-interview-question-for-c

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50447/favorite-c-interview-question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269838/interview-question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532102/can-a-pointer-ever-point-to-itself

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055141/interview-question-about-virtual-functions-in-c

Answer (score 3):

My favorite question to ask is a simple one:

a) Did you start with C and then switch to C++?

b) If so, then what were the first few things you learned to do differently?

This answer usually gives me a bead on how the programmer approaches C++ and his/her grasp of OOP and C++ in general.

there's no "Right" or "Wrong" answer here, but usually it's a great way to get a sense of where the candidate is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

I would actually present the person with a bit of code from another programming language that was object oriented and preferably not on the list of languages they know. The code should represent a simple task done in that language.

The point of this would not be to determine their knowledge of C++ but find out how well they understand programming. When you understand the basic concepts behind programming, then you can solve problems.

Answer (score 1):

How do you implement Virtual Functions in C++ , explain a real world scenario.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, I would say: "How would you go about implementing a move constructor for a container?"

My rationale is that, because move constructors are a feature of the next standard and not the current one, the candidate's answer will indicate whether the developer in question actively pursues knowledge about their language or just sticks to the tricks they know.

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd ask their opinion of the design of, say, `std::string`. I'd also ask them if they've used other designs (e.g., MFC/ATL `CString`, `wxString`, etc.) and assuming they have, ask them to compare and contrast the designs.

Strings are widely enough used that almost anybody with real experience using C++ should have used at least one or two of the above. Almost all designs embody some compromises between theoretical purity and practical use. Some can work really well, but only if used exactly as intended, while others trade greater versatility for some possible clumsiness. In short, almost anybody who has real experience *should* be able to express some meaningful opinions of their designs and those opinions should tell you a fair amount about how they think, how *they* design code, the degree to which they value pragmatism versus theoretical purity, and so on.